# Android: iwlist scan returns interface doesn't support scanning

Tags: android, wireless

I have used a Git project that builds iwlist and couple of other wireless program on android, when I 
try to run iwlist scan on one of my android tablet, it returns

rmnetctl  Interface doesn't support scanning.

**wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning.**

sit0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

dummy0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

rmnet0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

ip6tnl0   Interface doesn't support scanning.

I try to use netcfg for wlan0, but the output shows it's indeed up. And strange is if I run the same
program on my android phone there is indeed output. Is there a solution for this kind of problem?

Comment: Just add a comment about some new results so that people can know more about the problem. When I execute iwconfig on the device, it returns: **wlan0     no wireless extensions.**